# How check if a specific sensor exists on a device?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-sensors, google-play

I'm developing an android app that uses Sensors and I would like to know the best way to detect if a device has a specific sensor, let's say, a Proximity Sensor.

Also, is there any "filter" that can be applied to the manifest so users who don't have a proximity sensor won't be able to **install the app**?
If exists, will this "filter" also be valid on Google Play, so users won't be able to **see the app**?

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) is a reference to working with Android sensors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is most likely what you are looking for in checking the features programtically

```
PackageManager PM= this.getPackageManager();
boolean gps = PM.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
boolean acc = PM.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
```

This link explains what you can do to filter your application in the marketplace, look specifically at the  section

[Market Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html)

Comment: This solves part of the problem, thanks, but how can I specify that the app requires a specific hardware (proximity sensor) on the android manifest ?

Comment: I've checked the Market Filters and voilá, `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.proximity" />`, tks !

Comment: After  putting `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.proximity" />` in the Manifest file, Play Store says `0 devices supported` :(

Comment: Be a bit careful... <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.proximity" android:required="false" /> and check the PackageManager for availability

Answer (score 0):

For checking specific sensor:

```
public String getSystemInfo(PackageManager pm/* activity.getPackageManager() */) {
    return ""
    + "\nSDK: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
    + "\nMODEL: " + Build.MODEL
    + "\nBrand: " + Build.BRAND
    + "\nManufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER
    + "\nAndroid Version: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE
    + "\nSen-Fingerprint: " + hasFP()

    + "\nSen-Light: " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_LIGHT)
    + "\nSen-Compass: " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS)
    + "\nSen-Proximity: " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_PROXIMITY)
    + "\nSen-ECG(API 21): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE_ECG)
    + "\nSen-Temp(API 21): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE)
    + "\nSen-Accelerometer: " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER)
    + "\nSen-Humidity(API 21): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY)
    + "\nSen-Gyroscope(API 9): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_GYROSCOPE)
    + "\nSen-Barometer(API 9): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_BAROMETER)
    + "\nSen-HeartRate(API 20): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE)
    + "\nSen-StepCounter(API 19): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER)
    + "\nSen-StepDetector(API 19): " + hasSen(pm, PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR);
}
```

```
public boolean hasFP() {
    return (Build.FINGERPRINT != null && !Build.FINGERPRINT.equals(""));
}
```

```
public boolean hasSen(PackageManager packageManager, String sensor) {
    try {
        return packageManager.hasSystemFeature(sensor);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return false;
    }
}
```